# Securing links on left sidebar

Tags: 2013

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-prem installation, and we have a requirement that a section of one of the sites (specifically a list) be viewable by all users. No other part of this site is to be visible, with the exception of a single link (ideally in the left sidebar) that leads to a different SharePoint site (which is also accessible by everyone).

I can secure the list to an acceptable level, but since the permissions are not granted on the site, the left and top navigation bars are not visible. If I grant view access on the site level and secure all other elements of the site, both navigation bars remain unchanged (the user can still navigate to those locations, but they appear empty).

Is there a way to apply security trimming to links on the left/top sections? In the past I may have been able to accomplish this with audience settings, but that appears to have gone away for sidebar links.

Answer (score 0):

I've used audience targeting in the past on web parts that I want to have granular control on but I've also used the Security Trimmed Controls in SharePoint to remove chunks of the UI dependant on the users.

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="FullMask">
<div>
<SharePoint:SPLinkButton id="idNavLinkViewAll" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx" Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent%>" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/>
```

The permission string is where you control who see what.

[image]

Cheers,

S

Comment: The problem is the left navigation bar is not a web part, and I don't know where the left sidebar would render from -- I can't find any lists or information that would contain the list of links. I don't want to hide the entire sidebar, but some of the contents of the sidebar. Ideally what I'm looking for would be a list that I could set access to specific records on.

Comment: No its not a web part, you will need to access the Master Page in order to use the SP STC...you could also use CSS and a STC to achieve this. Depends on what you want to take out i guess.